# Adding new Data in ArrayList with Custom DataType

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having problem working with custom DataType. Does ArrayList behave like this. My instantiation of ArrayList with type CustomDataType refers to same memory according to the behavior that I'm observing.

For instance,
My custom DataType is:

```
public class CustomDataType{
     int id; String name; 
     public CustomDataType(int id, String name){...}
}
```

I used this DataType to store some value.

```
ArrayList<CustomDataType> person = new ArrayList<CustomDataType>(); //1a
CustomDataType cdt = new CustomDataType(12333333,"John Doe");
methodThatDoesSomething(person.add(cdt)); // method that takes ArrayList<E>
person.clear(); // 1b
```

Now When I do:

```
ArrayList<CustomDataType> person = new ArrayList<CustomDataType>(); //2a
CustomDataType cdt = new CustomDataType(1231231,"Jane Doe");
methodThatDoesSomething(person.add(cdt));
```

In this application, I'm referring to an object in 1a and 2a. When I change the name from John Doe to Jane Doe. My initial person Arraylist also gets "Jane Doe" instead of "John Doe". So, I have two Jane Doe. Any idea what is happening with this reference type. I have tried using list of Arraylist to solve this but whatever I do referencing is replacing older values.

> Addition info:

```
ArrayList<ActionModel> data = new ArrayList<ActionModel>();
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < my_action_items.length(); i++) {
    // parsing the data 
    JSONObject obj = my_action_items.getJSONObject(i);
    String id_main = obj.getString("id");
    int numb_of_step = obj.getInt("numb_of_step");
    String title_main = obj.getString("name");
    JSONObject sub_obj = apiResult.getJSONObject(id_main);
    int j = 0;

    // problem in action: action is alway the same for all cases. 
    ArrayList<SubAction> action = new ArrayList<SubAction>(); // HERE
    action.clear();

    for (j = 0; j < numb_of_step; j++) {
        // data parsing
        String name = sub_obj.getString("" + j);
        Boolean isComplete = sub_obj.getBoolean("completed" + j);
        String id = sub_obj.getString("step_id" + j);
        SubAction subAction = new SubAction(name, id, isComplete);
        action.add(subAction); // adding new data
    }
    // number of action is dedicated by 'my_action_items.length()' but all the data
    // inside the action is copy of last element.
    ActionModel ad = new ActionModel(action, id_main, numb_of_step, title_main, false, false);
    data.add(ad); // instance to data added 
    Boolean flag = action.isEmpty();
}
```

> More Detail

```
// Underlying flow of the code    
ArrayList<ActionModel> data = new ArrayList<ActionModel>();

//------ [1]---
SubAction[] st = null;
SubAction subAction = new SubAction("John Doe", "123123123", true);
st = new SubAction[1];
st[0] = subAction;
ActionModel ad = new ActionModel((st == null) ? st : st, "300", 2, "This is a test"+0, false, false);
data.add(ad);

//-------[2]---

SubAction[] st1 = null;
SubAction subAction1 = new SubAction("Jane Doe", "123123123", true);
st1 = new SubAction[1];
st1[0] = subAction1;
ActionModel ad1 = new ActionModel((st == null) ? st1 : st1, "2", 2, "This is a test" + 1, false, false);
data.add(ad1);

//// SAME ADDRESS //////
SubAction[] actions = data.get(0).getSubAction(); // same address 
SubAction[] anotherActions = data.get(1).getSubAction(); // same address
```

Both Results in "Jane Doe".

Comment: It's tough to see this without a bit more context.  Could you show us the method(s) you're invoking when you create these array lists?  The immediate smell is that you're creating two separate lists with two separate points of data, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: @Makoto, I did add the extra code that I'm using. Sorry if it's hard to decipher. My apology.

Comment: must understand what is Java refference. Replacing object value for instance not wanted to be replaced is typical error.

Comment: put SHORT code representing problem. Your example has many different goals not in core problem

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect the example you wrote above. Could you precise what you receive, what you expect and what you get?

Comment: @JacekCz actually I have included abstraction of the problem up above. Detail of the problem is basically parsing Json object to obtain some data to use for my CustomTypeData.

Comment: ...And/Or  Or maybe could you make a simple Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @C.Champagne, Sure. I will try to make it as simple as possible. Well

Comment: @C.Champagne, Well  ArrayList<SubAction> action = new ArrayList<SubAction>(); // HERE is where I'm creating the ArrayList with customType. I'm running this code for multiple time inside the inner for-loop. There are multiple action so I'm using ArrayList to add those into the list.  For every upper For-loop it should assigned different value to the ActionModel 'ad' --ActionModel ad = new ActionModel(action,...); --but in this code I'm only getting last action repeated for all ad's action. Basically last action replaces other preceding actions.

Comment: Abnormal behavior I'm having is at this line -- ArrayList<SubAction> action = new ArrayList<SubAction>(); -- It is referring to same action as if action is 'global variable'. When I add "Jane doe" in action, this will replace other stuff "Joe doe". My older data is connected in -- ArrayList<ActionModel> data; -- so when I log old stuff I see 2 "Jane Doe" instead of "John Doe" and "Jane Doe".

Comment: @user256419 Sorry but you explanations are a bit confusing. Creating a minimal complete end verifiable example with all the the changes you make would help. I don't see any input. I don't see where your object is modified...Anyway I suspect something and write an answer

Comment: @C.Champagne, Sorry it is hard to explain but I have added simple codes in initial example. I have been stuck with this for so long. If I can't solve this by mid-night. I will go ask for help at my University.

Comment: Found the bug. Action had a list of SubAction as its property which was declared as static by my friend. I should have looked at the model of Action first. Thanks everybody for the help and tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the root cause in the code you presented but I suspect from what you explained that you modified an object contained in an `ArrayList` from "outside" and were surprised it was also modified in the List.

```
ArrayList<SubAction> subActions = new ArrayList<SubAction>(); 
SubAction subAction= new SubAction("Action name 1", "id1", true);
subActions.add(subAction);
```

If you do the following:

```
System.out.println(subActions.get(0).getName())
```

You get:

> Action name 1

Now, if you go on with:

```
subAction.setName("Brand new name");
System.out.println(subActions.get(0).getName());
```

You get:

> Brand new name

Why?

Because in Java you only handle **references** to object and the the first item of the `subSections` list and `subSection`both point to the same object!

Just some additional side remarks:

1. Your `action.clear();` is totally useless because you just instanciated `action` which is thus already empty.
2. It is nice to name collections with a plural (`action` -> `actions`).
3. Java naming convention is came case (`id_main` -> `idMain`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try to follow those rules. This is actually a collaboration work and most of this section is written by my team-mate. He predominantly uses python hence property name such as id_main can be found here. I got lazy to change all the variables. However, I have not even touched action array anywhere else other than to get some Item value or to log it on console. No where have I set action anywhere other than above code.

Comment: Also, I have found something after countless hour of running through debugger. "SubAction[] actions = data.get(0).getSubAction(); SubAction[] anotherActions = data.get(1).getSubAction();" Points to same memory address for unknown reason. 'data' is ArrayList here that adds Action type.